# Fix Button position in Parent Activity when keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabs

We are using Fragment in Activity.Activity contain submit button and Fragment contain form inputs.

Now, when we open keyboard than that activity button come itself above the keyboard.How can we stick that button and move up just fragment portion.

[image]

[image]

We just want to stick that update button at the end.

Comment: you want your button above the keyboard??

Comment: No, that is already happening. I want to stick submit button on Parent activity. Just fragment need to be move up

Comment: show your xml file i think you have to set button in bottomParent = true

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if it work for you

Comment: No, I had already that code but it was not worked. I had solved using trick. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added this code and it works for me. This code will hide button when keyboard open and show it again when it is close.

```
 parentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its 
                    //Hide Show Key board
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view_two.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }else{
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        view_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to try this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, we have already added that code but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i get it right but you try to put this code in your **manifest** file inside **the activity tag:**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and put this code in you're button tag too :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```